# PHP Select * from two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a very simple auction website and I want to keep a user from bidding on an item when they are already the highest bidder, I want to keep that item from being displayed.

I have a table called bidhistory that stores the accountid of the bidder. What I have below is what I'm using to prevent a user from bidding on their own item. What would be the correct syntax for selecting from the bidhistory table as well? I hope I'm being clear enough.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM biditems WHERE NOT accountid = $accountid";
```

More of my code:

```
$accountid=$_SESSION['accountid'];

$sql=" SELECT * FROM biditems WHERE NOT accountid = $accountid";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "Items for Auction";
$expireDay=new DateTime('2015-07-19 20:12:50');
$theDay=new DateTime('now');
$timeToEnd=$expireDay->diff($theDay);
echo $timeToEnd->format('%R%a days');

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$itemid=$row['itemid'];
$item=$row['biditem'];
$auctionby=$row['username'];
$description=$row['biddesc'];

echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>$item auctioned off by $auctionby. <br> Description: $description
<br> 
<a href='acceptbid.php?itemid=$itemid&item=$item'>Place bid</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

And here are my tables.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE account (
accountid INT(100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE biditems (
itemid INT(100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
accountid INT(100),
biditem VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
biddesc tinytext,
dateadded DATETIME
)";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE bidhistory (
bidhistoryid INT(100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
accountid INT(100),
biditemid INT,
bidprice INT NOT NULL,
biddate DATETIME 
)";
```

Comment: post the both table names and primary key colum to join or to make sub query.

Comment: What is primary key of 2nd table?

Comment: it was not the question, but if you want your current statement working, you have to escape the string for the value: `$sql=" SELECT * FROM biditems WHERE NOT accountid = ".$accountid."";`

Comment: @Hassan, the primary key of the bidhistory table is bidhistoryid.

Comment: I believe you would want to create 2 separate queries. Can you explain why you would want them in one query? Sounds like they are 2 different checks: One to make sure they are not bidding on their item and another to make sure they are not bidding on an item they are the high bidder on.

Comment: @MaximilianAst, But it was already working?

Comment: What column is used to store the item in the bid history table? Is there an indicator telling which bid is the highest bid?

Comment: @BrianGerhards, The item is stored in the biditemid. And the bidprice tells which bid is the highest.

Comment: Please show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @LuluSparks - do you have a session of `$_SESSION["username"]`?

Comment: @LoganWayne, I have a session of `$_SESSION['accountid']`.

Comment: @LuluSparks - It would have been easier if you used `accountid` instead of `username` in your `biditems` table, assuming that in your `account`(?) table, it already has the `username` also. Is you username in `account` and `biditems` table unique? Meaning that a username won't be used again for new users?

Comment: @LoganWayne, I did use accountid in the biditems table. It did say username a few minutes ago, but that was a sloppy error on my part. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Note:

- You want to list all the items for bidding, but you don't want the user to bid on his/her own item? What we can do is to fetch all bid items, then a basic `if() else()` statement inside your `while loop()` to check each item if this items are auctioned by the users or not.
- It would be much easier if you used `accountid` for the `username` (*auction by*) in your `biditems` table so we can connect this table to `account` table much faster and easier on the part of indexing. Still, we can use `INNER JOIN` to connect the `biditems` table to your `account` table by using the `username` column (*hoping that usernames are all unique*).

You can work with this:

```
$sql=" SELECT a.itemid, a.biditem, a.biddesc, b.accountid, b.username FROM biditems a INNER JOIN account b ON a.username = b.username";
/* THE QUERY ABOVE WILL FETCH ALL BID ITEMS */

$result=mysql_query($sql); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */

echo "Items for Auction";
$expireDay=new DateTime('2015-07-19 20:12:50');
$theDay=new DateTime('now');
$timeToEnd=$expireDay->diff($theDay);
echo $timeToEnd->format('%R%a days');

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $itemid=$row['itemid'];
  $item=$row['biditem'];
  $auctionby=$row['username'];
  $description=$row['biddesc'];
  $auctionbyid = $row['accountid']; /* accountid OF THE AUCTION-ER */

  $result2 = mysql_query($con,"SELECT accountid FROM bidhistory WHERE biditem = '$itemid' ORDER BY bidhistoryid DESC LIMIT 1");
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $checkauctionid = $row2['accountid'];
  }

  echo '
    <ul>
      <li>'.$item.' auctioned off by '.$auctionby.'<br>
        Description: '.$desription.'<br>';

  if($accountid != $auctionbyid && $accountid != $checkauctionid){ /* IF THE ITEM IS NOT AUCTIONED BY THE USER OR HE/SHE WAS NOT THE HIGHEST BIDDER */
    echo '<a href="acceptbid.php?itemid='.$itemid.'&item='.$item.'">Place bid</a></li>';
  } /* END OF IF $accountid IS NOT THE SAME WITH $actionbyid */

  else { /* ELSE, IT MEANS THAT THIS ITEM IS HIS/HERS, SO HE/SHE CANNOT BID ON HIS/HER OWN ITEM OR THAT HE IS THE HIGHEST BIDDER FOR THIS ITEM */
    echo 'Cannot Place Bid';
  } /* END OF ELSE */

  echo '</ul>';
} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
```

- Make sure that in your `acceptbid.php` file that your query still checks if the item they are viewing are not auctioned by the user.
- And again, refrain from using `mysql_*` API as it is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) already.

Comment: I originally wanted to do this, but I kept getting an error. And when I used the code you just gave me, I got it again. It says the mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.

Comment: @LuluSparks - that error means that there is a mistake on your query. Show me your current query.

Comment: @LuluSparks - I think it was because I forgot to assign `account` table as `b`. I have updated my query.

Comment: This works perfectly for preventing a user from bidding on their own item! But now I'm not too sure how to keep a user from bidding if they're already the highest bidder...

Comment: @LuluSparks - updated my answer. You just have to use the answer I had for your previous question. And update the `if()` statement inside the `while loop()`